# Complexity for nested loops dividing by 2

Tags: c, loops, big-o

I am trying to figure out the complexity of a for loop using Big O notation. I have done this before in my other classes, but this one is more rigorous than the others because it is on the actual algorithm. The code is as follows:

```
for(i=n ; i>1 ; i/=2) //for any size n
{
    for(j = 1; j < i; j++)
    {
      x+=a
    }
}
```

I have arrived that the first loop is of O(log_2(n)). As for the second loop I am a little lost! Thank you for the help in the analysis.

Comment: How could you simplify the sum `n + n/2 + n/4 + ...` ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I don't get it how `n + n/2 + n/4 + ...` equals `nlogn`

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: It doesn't.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Then why two upvotes for the first comment?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: Presumably because some people thought (incorrectly) that it was the correct answer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What is the approximation of `n+n/2+n/4....` then?My maths is poor,but I still feel it is `n+logn`

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: If `n` is a power of two, then it's exactly `2n-1`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth why not (log(n)^(2^(log(n)+1))) -1 =O(n)

Comment: @WaldhomaAna: Huh?  How does that expression relate to this?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth sorry i mean You decrement the outer loop i by diving by 2, and in the inner loop you run i times, so the number of iterations will be a sum over all the powers of two less than or equal to N but greater than 0, which is n^(log(n)+1) - 1, so O(n).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth If it's `O(n)`, it is also `O(n*log n)`, so that is not _wrong_.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth normally when calculating O (Bigoh) you did't need  too much details. but ia in class i need all details for my exams

Comment: @OliCharlesworth is `2n-1=n+n/2+n/4......` a series formula?Basic maths?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is log(n) very less compared to `n` when `n` is large and hence can be ignored?That's why `O(n)=O(n*logn)`?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: He's alluding to the fact that O(n) is a subset of O(n log n).  (i.e. any function that is asymptotically bounded from above by `k.n` is also bounded by `k.n.log(n)`.)

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture The two classes `O(n)` and `O(n*log n)` are different, but `O(n)` is a sublcass of `O(n*log n)` (and of `O(n²)`, `O(2^n)`, `O(n!)`). If you have some upper bound `f(n)`, each _larger_ function is also an upper bound, so if `loop(n) <= C*n`, which says that `loop` is in `O(n)`, then trivially `loop(n) <= C*n*log n` for `n >= base_of_log`, and hence `loop` is also in `O(n*log n)`.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am bookmarking this question so that once I finish a book on algorithms,what you said will make complete sense to me!!

Comment: @Daniel Fischer what your complexity of the problem ?

Comment: @WaldhomaAna `O(n)` is the sharp bound. As stated above, each larger function would also provide a correct upper bound, but that would not be sharp. The loop is `Θ(n)`, meaning the number of iterations is bounded from below by a constant multiple of `n`, and from above, `c*n <= loop_iterations(n) <= C*n` for some `0 < c <= C`.

Comment: that mean compexity for that it o(n) ??

Comment: @OliCharlesworth http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401937/how-is-nn-2n-4-1-equal-to-2n-1-using-the-formula-for-geometric-series/401948#401948

Comment: When a loop's increment/decrement is multiplication/division, we say it is a logarithmic loop.

Answer (score 4):

To formally solve the your algorithm's time complexity, you may use the following steps with Sigma notation:

[image]

Also, take a look a the last slide of this very interesting [document](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt) by Dr. Jauhar.

Answer (score 3):

The overall number of iterations of inner loop is n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1 which is approximately 2n. So the complexity is O(n).

Answer (score 3):

Complexity should be `O(n)`. It forms a geometric series (not exactly but approximately).

The loop runs for `n+ n/2 + n/4 + .... +1` which is approx `2n`.

And `O(2n) = O(n)`.